Приложение Ar unity вместо изображения камеры выводит черный экран
С начало приложение работает нормально запускается сцена с главным меню, но при переходе на сцену с функциями AR вместо того, чтобы выводить изображение с камеры телефона оно отображает черный экран. Всё настраивал как в этом видео. Единственное я сделал свой AndroidManifest потому что изначально при запуске сцены с AR, приложение так и вовсе вылетало, теперь хоть это не происходит.
Вот так выглядит мой файл.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <application>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>



Добро пожаловать на сайт, Илья Тупиков. Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста, как задать вопрос на ресурсе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
